# What is the best way to get multiple objects using a List of Keys on Google App Engine (Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdoql

I have a many-to-many relationship. Just like in the example from the documentation:

```
Person.java
    private Set<Key> favoriteFoods;

Food.java
    private Set<Key> foodFans;
```

How do I get all "favorite foods" of a certain "food fan", if i have retrieved a "Person" object and i have the favoriteFoods key set. Is there a better way than:

```
for (Key k: favoriteFoods)
{ foodObjectsCollection.add( pm.getObjectById(Food.class, k) ); }
```

What's the cheapest and most efficient option here? I usually have to generate tables with object data in my app.

Comment: You may get some more help in addition to @Andrei's answer from my old question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474056/what-does-p-mean-in-a-jdo-query

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need [JDOQL](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html). For this concrete task try:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Food.class, ":p.contains(key)");
query.execute(favoriteFoods);
```

`contains()` behaves just like `IN` statement in SQL, so this query will fetch all Food objects from specified key set.

Comment: In terms of quota and limitations, couple short questions:
1. Does every getObjectById in my method is going to use 1 API call?
2. Using your method, do i have any limitations like.. max 5000 entries i can execute this JDOQL query on?

Comment: 1) yes, every call from Java to datastore is treated as separate API call. You will have to make complex queries by hand to pass it around. 2) as far as I know, there's no other limitations except those which are listed in their [Quotas](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html) section.